# Unexpected click behaviour on link + popup click in Google iOS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, facebook

I'm having following problem. I have following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Click Me test site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" co-target="http://apple.com">Click Me</a>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var handler = function codeclick(event) {
                var link_new = $('a').attr('co-target');

                if (link_new) {
                    window.open(link_new, '_blank');
                }
            }
            $('a').bind('click.codeclick', handler);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://gurzeda.co/click-test.html)

The expected behaviour on desktop is that the page in co-target attribute is opened in new tab/window and the one in href attribute is opened in current tab.

On internal mobile facebook browser it should open just the co-target attribute page (intended). But on Google mobile iOS app it opens the page in href attribute (unintended).

Does anyone encountered similar problem before and maybe have some clues what should I do to make it right? There is no need that the page in co-target has to open. I just want it that on both facebook and google app it open one of it, not different one in each.

Comment: What is _Google mobile iOS app_ ?

Comment: Here is the link to appstore: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-app-search-made-just/id284815942?mt=8
Basically it's Google Search app.

Comment: I don’t see you preventing the click default action anywhere – so it seems only natural that the link in the href attribute is opened.

Comment: Preventing the click and writing window.location.href has no effect whatsoever. Even if I change position of window.open and window.location.href it doesn't matter.